# Checking for root (via /system/xbinx/su) Android Q (Google APIs vs Google Play)

Tags: android, android-emulator, root, android-virtual-device

I'm performing root checks during application startup by utilizing [RootBeer](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer). One of the common checks for root is by checking for the existence of `/system/xbin/su`.

I've noticed that emulators running an Android Q x86 (with *Google APIs*) image contain this file, and thus the root check returns `true`. However, emulators running an Android Q x86 image (with *Google Play*) do not contain `/system/xbin/su`, and thus the root check returns `false`.

**Questions:**

1. Why is this file present on the emulator with Android Q (Google APIs) but *not* present on Android Q (with Google Play)?
2. Similarly, is checking for `/system/xbin/su` bound to result in false positives when attempting to detect root? Is that file often present on normal non-rooted devices?